# Why does pyplot.quiver plots vectors with infinite length?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a 5X10 matrix of vectors using pyplot.quiver :

```
from pylab import *

COLUMN_RESOLUTION = 10
ROW_RESOLUTION = 5

plotBorders = 2
X,Y = meshgrid(arange(COLUMN_RESOLUTION),arange(ROW_RESOLUTION)) # X,Y positions of vectors
U = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

V = [0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

lim = 10
xlim(-1*lim,lim)
ylim(-1*lim,lim)
quiver(X,Y, U, V)
show()
```

The resulting figure has vectors with infinite length - no matter how much I extend the axes (the parameter *lim*) The arrows' head is not seen :

**lim = 10**
[image]

**lim = 100**
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "scale" parameter in the quiver command:

```
quiver(X,Y, U, V, scale=20.0)
```

Comment: I think it's very strange that the vector length does not default to the same scale as the rest of the graph, but it doesn't.

Comment: Another feature to note when using scale is that (from the documentation) :" a smaller scale parameter makes the arrow longer". http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver

Comment: Setting the scale to 20 have solved it for me as well, but I find it very strange that the vectors span infinitely without a scale.